# WPF+PRISM+MEF initializing DownloadedPartCatalogCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

I am trying to initialize a module from my MefBootStrapper implementation

```
Type type = typeof(OrderDetailsModule.OrderDetailsModule);

ModuleInfo mi = new ModuleInfo {
    ModuleName = type.Name,
    Ref = new Uri(type.Assembly.Location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri,
        InitializationMode =InitializationMode.WhenAvailable,
        ModuleType = type.AssemblyQualifiedName
    };

this.ModuleCatalog.AddModule(mi);
```

I get an error

> failed to load type for module OrderDetailsModule. \r\nError was:
>   Unable to locate the module with type
>   'OrderDetailsModule.OrderDetailsModule, OrderDetailsModule,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' among the
>   exported modules. Make sure the module name in the module catalog
>   matches that specified on ModuleExportAttribute for the module type.."

Digging down Prism, in MefModuleInitializer, there is an  `if (this.downloadedPartCatalogs.TryGet(moduleInfo, out partCatalog))` and the downloaded parts is empty. I can see in the MefModuleInitializer class, downloadedPartCatalogs is injected via the ImportingConstructor attribute.

This is my OrderDetailsModule class

```
[Export("OrderDetailsModule")]
public class OrderDetailsModule
{
}
```

Question is, where do i export the downloadedPartCatalogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module class must implement the `IModule` interface and be attributed with the ModuleExportAttribute.

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(ModuleD))]
public class ModuleD : IModule 
{...}
```

Or use the AssemblyCatalog to automatically to discover and load modules.

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ModuleA).Assembly));
    this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ModuleC).Assembly));
    . . .
}
```

Please read the Prism documentation: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/30-ModularApplicationDevelopment.md#modules-in-mef

Comment: Adding ModuleExport resolved the error. But my view model is not initialized yet. From what i understand, that will be delayed until the view will actually be placed in a region. May be there is a better way to do this, but for now can I force creation of my view model? I tried PartCreationPolicy [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] (Expecting to create a  singleton instance at startup). What i am doing is do a [ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.OrderDetails)] to a small region to make prism load my view model.